# Wordpress failing to load graphics after migrating

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress failing to load graphics after migrating. when I bring back the old site graphics come and everything works on the new domain - but if I delete the old domain files everything dies.

Comment: How did you migrated your website ? used any plugin ?

Comment: Are your graphics still referencing the location you migrated to? I've used the plugin Duplicator [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) many times for migration I would give that try.

Comment: @moneeb I migrated manually by backing up files and uploading to the new host same applies to the db file. After investigating the DB file on the option table there is no place for url ...

Comment: You can try @Hillel solution or you can use All-in-One WP Migration
 plugin -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your images are still being pulled from the old website.
This happens because you didn't update your posts on the Database for the new domain.

If you have access to your WordPress dashboard, you may want to try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Search for:
olddomain.com

Replace with:
newdomain.com

Some things to consider:

1. As always, make a backup of your DB before you start
2. Don't add http:// or https:// to your search/replace strings, and no trailing '/'
3. Do include subdomains and/or folder if applicable (e.g. subdomain.olddomain.com/my-wordpress)